# on Linux, how to change file name from blah_m_n_12192012.txt to blah_m_n.txt

Tags: linux, file-rename, mv

where m, n could be any number from 0 to 100, for example

```
blah_5_9_12192012.txt -> blah_5_9.txt
blah_4_35_12192012.txt -> blah_4_35.txt
```

I tried doing the following but it didn't work

```
mv blah_?_*_12192012.txt blah_?_*.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in blah_?_*_12192012.txt
do
  mv $file ${file/_12192012/}
done
```